# Rails 3.1 ssl is used even if I disabled ssl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added `force_ssl` in my `ApplicationController`, and deleted later, but now, every request is still prompted to https. I have tried to add `config.force_ssl = false` to all the configuration files in `application.rb` and `environments/development.rb`, etc., but it doesn't work. When I reboot the server, the requests are still converted to https. Any clue?

**Updates**:
This happens only when I request the root of the application, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/`, however in my config/routes.rb file I have specified the url for the root clearly: `root :to => 'home#index'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're seeing the effects of [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)'s `max-age`, which is set by `Rack::SSL` (which `config.force_ssl = true` sets up) to something high.

Comment: You are correct, and @Adrein_Lamonthe answer to clear the browser cache it made the config.force_ssl = false app changes effective on my computer

Answer (score 3):

In addition to rebooting your app, you also have to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

For those who it's still unclear, here is what I did to do the trick.

In application_controller.rb :

```
before_filter :expire_hsts

[...]
private
  def expire_hsts
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'max-age=0'
  end
```

In production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

**Clear the cache** of your web browser and that's it !

Answer (score 0):

yfeldblum is absolutely correct. Disabling it and making chrome forget the header can be a pain.

Here's what I ended up putting in my config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::SSL, hsts: false, exclude: proc { |env|
  !env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?('/manage')
})
```

** note A: hsts: false is the critical bit

** note B: I'm using 1.9, so my hash syntax might be different than yours.

Beyond that, I had to open this url in Chrome chrome://net-internals/#hsts and remove the domains that had this header set.

Thankfully this didn't make it to production, because Rack::SSL sets a very long expires on this header.

Answer (score 0):

if are you using nginx see option:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

and disable it!